# Nocedal & Wright — direction for constrained optimization with one inequality constraint

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, constraints, gradient-descent

I'm reading Nocedal & Wright's [Numerical Optimization](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-40065-5). On page 322, on optimization with one inequality constraint, right after equation 12.18, the text says that when we are in a region where $ c_1(x) > 0$ (where $c_1(x)$ is the constraint), the direction ($f(x)$ is the objective function to be minimized)

$$d = -c_1(x) \frac{\nabla f(x)}{||\nabla f(x)||}$$

satisfies equation 12.18, which is

$$c_1(x) + \nabla c_1(x)^T d \geq 0$$

This should hold if

$$ \frac{\nabla c_1(x)^T \nabla f(x)}{||\nabla f(x)||} < 1$$

But I don't see why this should be true. If there were another $$||\nabla c_1(x)||$$ in the denominator, it might have held. Can someone shed light on what I might be missing?

Comment: Since the link to the PDF file is broken, I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.

As mentioned on point $43$ of the Errata. The denominator should contain an extra factor $\left\| \nabla c_1(x)\right\|$.

I am attaching the [Errata](http://users.iems.northwestern.edu/~nocedal/book/2ndprint.pdf) of the book.